# jquery tmpl accessing sub elements in nestd array

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I am using jQuerys "tmpl" plugin for templates. Now i have an array with elements that are arrays as well and i have to access specific elements.

i.e. the array would be:

```
var arr = {
  'id':23422,
  'title':'example',
  'images': {'small':'34fge.jpg','original':'dfsdf354.jpg'}
};
```

And now in the temple i'd like to access arr[images][small] but it doesn't work. What i am trying is:

```
<div>
  <h3>${title}</h3>
  <img src="${arr}{images}{small}" />
</div>
```

Anyone any help/ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<img src="${images.small}" />` that will give the following markup:

```
<div>
  <h3>example</h3>
  <img src="34fge.jpg">
</div>
```

In fact, the `images` property isn't a  nested `array` but a `object` with properties.

But if you really want to loop through a nested array, then you should use a [nested template](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/) and change your syntax a little bit (note the [] around images property):

**Javascript**

```
var arr = {
    'id': 23422,
    'title': 'example',
    'images': [
        { 'small': '34fge.jpg', 'original': 'dfsdf354.jpg' },
        { 'small': '35fge.jpg', 'original': 'dfsdf.jpg' }
    ]
};
```

**Templates**

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   <div>
     <h3>${title}</h3>
     {{tmpl(images) "#imagesTemplate"}}
   </div>
</script>
<script id="imagesTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
     <img src="${small}" />
     <img src="${original}" />
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the Advice, thou i am already iterating. I might add another sub template taking care of the image thing. Good Idea.

Comment: Can you please tell me ?How to pass multiple values to a  sub template like {{tmpl(arg1,arg2)}}?? and how to access them in the subtemplate?

Comment: Can you please create a new topic with your question? Otherwise people with the same issue would not find it. Thank u.